# Google Sheets Arrayformula on both horizontal & vertical cells?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrayformula

In a sheet, I make calculations horizontally, however I can't build the arrayformula to expand calculation vertically on each row.
See the following sheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FbeoKhiJ3jqYXqfIgAK_tHXPZ_Z1Xrm33ulu9gomXuE/edit#gid=16063565

[image]

Select the tab "arrayformula", and point to the formula in column F

```
=COUNTA(B3:E3)
```

How can I apply arrayformula so it can expand to all the rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A3:A), 
 MMULT(IFERROR(LEN(B3:E)/LEN(B3:E), 0), TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(B2:E2)^0)), ))
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 4):

Digging the web I have found a [Google Post](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/YsqvgpnxLwE;context-place=topicsearchin/docs/authorid$3AAPn2wQcRbxwSsMc0vz-niYVVrT5MyI9JQGqbQ_g9FDK5-Fwx6WMyXI7teSZvq1Q_YjwLVQEY0Y54%7Csort:date%7Cspell:false) that states:

> Aggregating functions such as `sum()` will not produce multi-cell
>   results in an `arrayformula()` wrapper. To calculate row-by-row totals
>   of the numeric values in columns `A` to `C` from row `2` down, use simple
>   addition instead of `sum()`:
>
> `=arrayformula( A2:A + B2:B + C2:C )`
>
> When there are lots of columns, or if the array to be totaled
>   row-by-row is not a range but another array expression, use `mmult()`:
>
> ```
> =arrayformula( 
>                 mmult( A2:C; transpose(sign(column(A2:C))) 
>                       ))
> ```
>
> See the illustrative sheet prepared by Top Contributor APL+ for more
>   information on `mmult()` usage.
>
> Some other aggregating functions that are not conducive for use in an
>   array formula are listed below with examples of workarounds for
>   producing row-by-row results.
>
> `and()` -- use **boolean arithmetic**:
>
> ```
> =arrayformula( if( (A2:A = "OK") * (B2:B > 10); "Ready"; "" ) )
> ```
>
> `or()` -- use **boolean arithmetic**:
>
> ```
> =arrayformula( if( (A2:A = "Yes") + (A2:A = "Maybe"); "Positive"; "" ) )
> ```
>
> `average()` -- use `addition` and `division`:
>
> ```
>    =arrayformula( (A2:A + B2:B + C2:C) / 3 )
> ```
>
> `count()` -- use `isnumber()` and `+`:
>
> ```
>   =arrayformula( isnumber(A2:A) + isnumber(B2:B) + isnumber(C2:C) )
> ```
>
> `counta()` -- use `not(isblank())` and `+`:
>
> ```
>   =arrayformula( not(isblank(A2:A)) + not(isblank(B2:B)) + not(isblank(C2:C)) )
> ```
>
> `concatenate()` -- use the `&` operator:
>
> ```
>   =arrayformula( A2:A & B2:B & C2:C )
> ```
>
> `join()` -- use the `&` operator:
>   =arrayformula( A2:A & ", " & B2:B & ", " & C2:C )
>
> `max()` -- use `if()`:
>
> ```
>     =arrayformula( if(A2:A > B2:B; A2:A; B2:B) )
> ```
>
> `min()` -- use `if()`:
>
> ```
>     =arrayformula( if(A2:A < B2:B; A2:A; B2:B) )
> ```
>
> `product()` -- use the `*` operator:
>
> ```
>    =arrayformula( A2:A * B2:B * C2:C )
> ```

Comment: This answer is a lifesaver!